# Using Typeahead with iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I am trying to implement autocomplete using Twitter typeahead library for a iFrame so that When I start typing in iframe the suggestions should start showing up but it isnt.

**HTML Code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="editorArea-frame" style="width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="iframe.js"></script>
```

**Javascript code**

```
var editorFrame = $('#editorArea-frame')[0];

var html = '';

html += '<style type="text/css">pre { background-color: #eeeeee; }</style>';

html += '<style type="text/css">html,body { cursor: text; } #editorDiv { display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow-y:scroll; outline: none;}</style>';

html += '<body></div><div id="editorDiv" contentEditable="true"></div></body>';

editorFrame.contentDocument.open();

editorFrame.contentDocument.write(html);

editorFrame.contentDocument.close();
```

When I execute this piece of javascript code the iframe becomes blank and its body becomes empty.Can anyone point me as to what am i doing wrong?

```
   $('#editorArea-frame').typeahead({
      source: function(typeahead, query) {  
      return ['alpha', 'beta', 'bravo', 'delta', 'epsilon', 'gamma', 'zulu'];
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must apply typeahead on an input field.
I would also advise avoiding iframe if you can. This may save you some brain cells.

Comment: ive implemented it successfully..thanks for the help

Comment: How did you do ? I'm trying to do but I can not @KartikJain